# map over zod objects to dynamically populate a form select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, zod, shadcnui

I have a Zod Object declared:

```
const FormSchema = z.object({
  field1: z.string(),
  field2: z.string(),
  field3: z.enum([
    "Option 1",
    "Option 2",
    "Option 3"
  ]),
});
```

to validate my shadcn form:

```
<form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <div>
              <FormField control={form.control} name="field1" render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Field 1</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                </FormItem>
              )} />

              <FormField control={form.control} name="field2" render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Field 2</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                </FormItem>
              )} />
            
              <FormField control={form.control} name="field3" render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Field 3</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <SelectTrigger>
                      <SelectValue />
                    </SelectTrigger>
                  </FormControl>
                  <SelectContent>
                    <SelectItem value="Option 1">Option 1</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="Option 2">Option 2</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="Option 3">Option 3</SelectItem>
                  </SelectContent>
                </FormItem>
              )} />
            </div>

          </form>
```

and this is fine, straight forward and works as intended.  Select options list however is very long so I'm trying to dynamically generate the `<SelectItem>'s` in the form, have tried every way to map over the zod object but can't find anything that works.  Is it even possible?

I considered creating a separate dataset consisting of the same data and mapping that, which works but I can't figure out how to populate the zod object with it so it seems impractical to effectively have the same data twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to dynamically create the `SelectItem` elements from your zod enum. If so, you want the [`.options`](https://zod.dev/?id=zod-enums) property of the `field3` property on your `FormSchema`'s [`shape`](https://zod.dev/?id=shape) (you may have to scroll around a bit, sadly the Zod website isn't good at deep linking):

```
<SelectContent>
    {FormSchema.shape.field3.options.map((option) => (
        <SelectItem key={option} value={option}>
            {option}
        </SelectItem>
    ))}
</SelectContent>
```

ZodEnum objects also have an `.enum` property which is an object with both the keys and values being the enum members, but `.option` seems more useful here.